# My discord bot is giving me permission errors

Tags: python, discord.py

The problem is that my bot has administrator permissions and I don't see how or why I am getting permission errors. This error pops up when the bot should be giving a role to a joining member.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    welcome_channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name='welcome_channel')
    guild=member.guild
    if guild.member_count % 10 ==1: #to find the last digit of the member count to see if st or nd or rd or th should be placed at the end
        embed=discord.Embed()
        embed2=discord.Embed()
        name=(member)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{random.choice(greetings)} {name}. You are the {guild.member_count}st member", icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        await welcome_channel.send(embed=embed)
        embed2.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        await welcome_channel.send(f"{random.choice(greetings)} {member.mention}. You are the {guild.member_count}st member", embed=embed2)
```

The exact errors that I get are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Python\VSC\Discord Bot\Main backup.py", line 53, in on_message
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in Traceback, the error probably doesn't come from `on_member_join()`, but from the [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) event

You should check the order of the roles of your server. If bot's role is below the role you want to give to a user, then your bot doesn't have the permission to do so (as explained [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/214836687-Role-Management-101))

Example :

[image: Screen]

Comment: I just tried it, and thanks for answering and helping me out Deden 77, but do you have an explanation for why this happens even though it has admin?

Comment: Yes, but even with administrator permission, if the bot's role is below, it won't succeed. Check [this page](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/214836687-Role-Management-101) for more infos

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks for your help bro.

Comment: Glad to help you